# Integrate: $ \iiint_Wz\ dxdydz ; W = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4; \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x \le y \le \sqrt{3}x\} $

Tags: integration

In solvining the following integral using spherical coordinates:

$$
\iiint_Wz\ dxdydz \\
W = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4; \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x \le y \le \sqrt{3}x\}
$$

I obtained the following (hopefully it is correct):

$$
0 \le r \le 2 \\
\frac{\pi}{6} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{3} \\
0 \le \phi \le \pi
$$

Then knowing that $z = r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}$ I obtained the following:
$$
I = \int_0^2 \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3} \int_0^\pi r^3\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}\ dr d\theta d\phi \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{d\theta}\ \int_0^\pi {\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}\ d\phi \\
\text{Using the trigonometric rule of equivalents: } \sin{x}\cos{x} = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2{x}: \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{\sin{\theta}d\theta} \int_0^\pi {\frac{1}{2}\sin^2{\phi}}\ d\phi \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{\sin{\theta}d\theta} *\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi {\sin^2{\phi}}\ d\phi \\
\text{Using the trigonometric rule of equivalents: } \sin^2{x} = \frac{1-\cos{2x}}{2}: \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{\sin{\theta}d\theta} *\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi {\frac{1-\cos{2\phi}}{2}}\ d\phi \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{\sin{\theta}d\theta} *\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\pi {1-\cos{2\phi}}\ d\phi \\
= \int_0^2{r^3dr} \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}{\sin{\theta}d\theta} *\frac{1}{4}[\int_0^\pi {1d\phi}-\int_0^\pi{\cos{2\phi}}\ d\phi] \\
$$

No I am having trouble with $\int\cos{2\phi} \ d\phi$. Would it be safe to say that $\int\cos{2\phi} \ d\phi = -\sin{2\phi}$?

Comment: It should be $0 \le \phi \le \pi$ (unless there's some condition $z \ge 0$ that you forgot to tell us about).

Comment: And also $z = r \cos \phi$ (the angle $\theta$ only affects $x$ and $y$).

Comment: @HansLundmark my mistakes, I made the changes but I seem to be running into the same issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac \pi6 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi3$ ?

Comment: @TiwaAina Yea, thanks. I changed it.

Comment: You've also put the limits for $\phi$ on the $r$ integral, and vice versa. Anyway, regarding the actual question, $\int \cos 2\phi \, d\phi=\frac12 \sin 2\phi + C$ (which should be well known long before you start doing triple integrals...).

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks. I came across this but was not sure if it was correct to do substitution like that. Could you post it as an answer? Btw, I was never introduced to the concepts of trigonometric equations.

Comment: You got another anwer anyway. But I find it really strange that you haven't seen how to integrate cosine. I'm assuming you're taking a multi-variable calculus course, since you're doing triple integrals, and before that you ought to have taken a single-variable calculus course, and I can't imagine a single-variable calculus course anywhere in the world where one doesn't teach how to do $\int \cos(kx) \, dx$...

Comment: @HansLundmark I am actually doing my studies in another country where the education system is different and the students would have already done most of the basics which is not the case with me. So I have to learn many of thd concepts on the go.

Comment: Oh, I see... Well, good luck then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\int_0^2{r^3\,\mathrm dr} \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}{\,\mathrm d\theta}\ \int_0^\pi {\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}\,\mathrm d\phi$$

Notice that $$\int_0^2 {\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}\,\mathrm d\phi$$ is of the form $$\int f(x) \, f'(x) \, \mathrm dx = \frac 12f(x)^2$$ Therefore $$\int_0^\pi {\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}\,\mathrm d\phi = \frac 12 \sin^2\phi \bigg|_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi} = 0$$

Hence $$\int_0^2{r^3\,\mathrm dr} \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}{\,\mathrm d\theta}\ \int_0^\pi {\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}}\,\mathrm d\phi = 0$$

---

There's an error in your working: $\color{red}{\sin\phi \cos\phi \neq \frac 12 \sin^2 \phi}$.

But continuing along your line of thinking, we'd say that

$$\int_0^\pi\cos{2\phi} \ d\phi = \frac 12 \sin(2\phi) \bigg|_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi} = 0$$

Comment: The region of integration is symmetric with respect to the $xy$-plane, and the integrand is an odd function with respect to the $xy$-plane, thus the integral is zero.